# How to connect MongoDB intermediate server in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Local server**: `11.18.3.1`

**Intermediate server**: `11.18.3.2`

**MongoDB Server**: `11.18.3.3`

Node application is running in `11.18.3.1` server. 
We can't connect directly to `11.18.3.3` (MongoDB server) from `11.18.3.1`. So first I need to connect `11.18.3.2` then `11.18.3.3`. the below code is not working. How can we do this? we need to pass first server stream into the second server.

```
var client = require('ssh2').Client;
server_ssh = new client();
server_ssh.on('ready', function() {
        ts_socket.emit('log', "Server connected");

        // from here I want to connect to MongoDB

        var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
      , Server = require('mongodb').Server;

        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('11.18.3.3', 27017));
        mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
          var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb");

          mongoClient.close();
        });


    }).connect(
    { "host": "11.18.3.2",
      "username":"myuser",
      "password":"mypassword",
      "port":22
    }
    );
```

please help.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here? Where is your MongoDB server? You should only need to connect to one unless for some reason you need to connect to two separate server instances. Usually you would not do this without a specific reason. Most use cases would employ multiple MongoDB instances as part of a replica set or sharded cluster, for which connection to those is different to what you seem to be asking here.

Comment: Mongodb installed in C server. I cant connect C server from A server. So first i will connect B server by using node-ssh2 function and then connect mongodb database in C server. B server is like intermediate or proxy server.

Comment: Here's the point. Regardless of where your application is running, the server it needs to connect to ( ie connection string ) is the server where MongoDB is installed. No other server addresses matter to the database connection.

Comment: i have modified my question.

Comment: any idea about this issue

Comment: That looks like something you just cannot do at an application level. You would effectively need to set up a secure tunnel at the system level between the sockets you can connect to and then connect your application to that socket, which will pass through to the target MongoDB instance. This would therefore be a networking configuration question rather than a programming question. Ask on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com), as that is what that site is for.

Comment: @selvan How your intermediate server (B Server) is communication with the MongoDB (i.e. C server) ..I believe instead of A server you need to check the implementation at B Server

Comment: we can ssh from B to C. But we cant ssh from A to C. So i want to ssh from A to B then database connect from B to C.

Comment: From A to B using ssh connection. Then B to C using mongoclient function.Here B is the intermediate server. Without  B server we cant connet C server.